# MVC callbackUrl remove text before guid

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I"m currently working on registration confirmation for my website and made a callbackurl like this:

```
var callbackUrl = Url.Action("RegisterActivation","Account", new { activationToken }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
```

and the body:

```
string body = @"<h4>Welcome!</h4><p></p><p>To get started, please click <a href=""" + callbackUrl + @""">here</a> to activate your account.</p>";
```

The output of the callbackUrl is like this:

http://localhost:3910/Account/RegisterActivation?activationToken=enuAygun40yAWnQMJsX2yA

Now the problem is that "new { activationToken }" sets activationToken= before the token, Is there a easy way to remove this so it only links the token itself?

Example: http://localhost:3910/Account/RegisterActivation?enuAygun40yAWnQMJsX2yA

Comment: Url in form of `http://example.com/blah?parameter` is not valid, and just `parameter` is not a valid query string that is supposed to come after `?`. You can have something like `http://example.com/blah/parameter`, would that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the default route registration pattern in place, you can simply change your parameter name to `id`.

```
public ActionResult RegisterActivation(string id)
{
  // use id value
}
```

Now you can do

```
Url.Action("RegisterActivation","Account", new { id="yourString" }, 
                                                           protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
```

This will generate a link like

```
http://localhost:3910/Account/RegisterActivation/enuAygun40yAWnQMJsX2yA
```